# How exactly are Amazon S3 byte-hours determined?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know from "How will I be charged and billed for my use of Amazon S3?"  in https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/ that AWS charges me for S3 storage according to the byte-hours that I've accumulated when I store something.  How **exactly** is this calculated.  Do they take a snapshot every hour or day or every five minutes or what?  Or, do they check every time I do a PUT (or POST) or a DELETE to a bucket?

Comment: Why do you ask? Is there something you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to understand how I am charged if, for example, I have a 10GB bucket, for example, that's created, used, and deleted within 10 minutes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are S3 (Amazon Simple Storage System) storage prices calculated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746250/how-are-s3-amazon-simple-storage-system-storage-prices-calculated)

Answer (score 2):

This is AWS internal information - You'll need to ask a TAM or open a ticket to AWS, but not sure they will submit that information.

In general - the resolution is hourly, you can see that the usage type is "TimedStorage-ByteHrs" and the DBR/CUR has a line for each hour with the amount of storage (for Standard and Infrequent Access and now also One-Zone Infrequent Access) per bucket (resourceid). objects that existed in a bucket for 10 minutes will be billed for an hour of storage, i.e if the price is $0.021 (public pricing after passing the 500TB tier) then 1GB stored for 10 minutes will be charged $0.021/.

What's the scenario? Why store something for 10 minutes on S3?

My educated guess is that they use the metadata of PUT requests along with creation times and mapping your storage by the hour. that way if a resource is still available each hour it'll remain in the billing, and it sits well with the actual billing of minimum a hour.